# Collapse and expand tables independently with same class name inside SharePoint wiki page

Tags: javascript, html, wiki-pages

I am trying to create collapsible sections with header (clickable) and description (details about header) inside a SharePoint wiki page. There will be multiple such sections inside the wiki page. Is there a better approach available to achieve this?
I tried to achieve this by adding a table of two rows (for each section). First row is marked as table header (click for show/hide section) and second is footer (description). Using JavaScript, tried to hide/show description while keeping the header for each table visible all the time. 
The problem is that when I click header of any of the tables, it will hide/show description for all the tables inside the wiki page on a single click no matter which section I click. This is because the header/footer class name is same for all the tables(with two rows only) I have inserted inside the wiki page.

**Is there a way to make sure only a particular section is affected independently when clicked?**
Note that, the class name can't be changed since tables are being created inside SharePoint wiki page.
following is the javascript i am using: the class names are same for all the tables inside the page.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".ms-rteTableFooterRow-Default").hide();
$(".ms-rteTableHeaderRow-Default").show();

$(".ms-rteTableHeaderRow-Default").click(function(){
$(".ms-rteTableFooterRow-Default").slideToggle();
});
});</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Inside header click function, find the closest and next footer row and then apply slide toggle on that instead of adding it on all footers.

Comment: Sadly, I'm not a javascript expert. Could you please help me with the code correction to apply slide toggle to closest footer? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using CSS and little bit javascrip code:

You need to convert your html content like given below:

```
<button class="ms-rteTableHeaderRow-Default">Section 1</button>
<div class="ms-rteTableFooterRow-Default">
  Div Contents
</div>

<button class="ms-rteTableHeaderRow-Default">Section 1</button>
<div class="ms-rteTableFooterRow-Default">
  Div Contents
</div>

<button class="ms-rteTableHeaderRow-Default">Section 1</button>
<div class="ms-rteTableFooterRow-Default">
  Div Contents
</div>
```

Then Use below CSS:

```
.ms-rteTableHeaderRow-Default {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .ms-rteTableHeaderRow-Default:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.ms-rteTableFooterRow-Default {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

Use below JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("ms-rteTableHeaderRow-Default");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
      acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var footer = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (footer.style.maxHeight){
          footer.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
          footer.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
        } 
      });
    }
});
```

Make sure `ms-rteTableHeaderRow-Default` and `ms-rteTableFooterRow-Default` are sibling elements of each other.

Reference:

[Collapsibles/Accordion](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_accordion_animate).